# How can I automate the installation of assemblies to the GAC over a network?

Tags: .net, deployment, gac, global-assembly-cache

I need to install the same assembly to the GAC for 30+ servers. I would prefer not to have to RDP to each server and install the assembly manual. Is there a straightforward way to install assemblies to the GAC over the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a straight forward solution to this problem.  Installing to the GAC requires commands to be run in addition to just placing the file on disk.  I thought about this for a bit and I came up with the following 2 ideas

1. Use PowerShell V2's remoting feature to run the command on all of the machines
2. Use Group Policy to run an MSI on every machine which will install the assembly

I think #1 has the best shot.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a regular requirement you may try some automation tools like CruiseControl.net, InstallAce or FinalBuilder. If this is one time requirement then certainly you may use the evaluation version of these tools.

Jared: I would be interested to know more about PowerShell remorting features. Does it eleminate the need of PowerShell pre-installed on all servers?

Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) also allow remote execution etc. but need to explore how to install file in GAC remotely otherwise WMI does allow other features like remote script exectuion etc.